# Unordered list is shown as nested in the on-site rendering but flat in the post editor

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, list

I use Chrome (latest version), and there is an obvious bug.

1. Look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546442/2377343).
2. Click to ["edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56546442/edit) that post and without making any changes, just look at that post how it looks like in the "Editor preview" page.

On my side, they look quite different (messed).

[image: on-site render has nested lists but editor live preview does not]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Markdown is messed up so the HTML result gets messed up as well. At least the *server-side* renderer does a better job at recovering.

Fix it by editing the list: remove the leading space and give the following lines two spaces. Now the client-side preview and server-side render show the same.

For reference: [CommonMark specification for Lists](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#lists)

These are not really bugs ([YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV)), just quirks how not properly used Markdown content gets treated differently by the two implementations. If an edit can fix it, prefer that route.

---

#### final result

---

Open the private channel, then:

- on **web** client:

  - look at the **URL** in your browser:
  - `if` it's for example https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c1192292378_2674311763110923980
  - `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID
- on **mobile** and **desktop**:

  - copy the **link** of *any* message of the channel:
  - `if` it's for example https://t.me/c/1192292378/31
  - `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID (bonus: **31** is the message ID)
- on **Plus Messenger** [for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus&hl=en):

  - open the **infos** of the channel:
  - the channel ID appears **above**, right under its name

---

`WARNING` be sure to **add -100 prefix** when using Telegram Bot API:

- `if` the channel ID is for example 1192292378
- `then` you should use **-1001192292378**

#### Original Markdown content

```
Open the private channel, then:

 - on **web** client:
- look at the **URL** in your browser:
- `if` it's for example https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c1192292378_2674311763110923980
- `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID

 - on **mobile** and **desktop**:
- copy the **link** of *any* message of the channel:
- `if` it's for example https://t.me/c/1192292378/31
- `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID (bonus: **31** is the message ID)

 - on **Plus Messenger** [for Android][1]:
- open the **infos** of the channel:
- the channel ID appears **above**, right under its name

----------

`WARNING` be sure to **add -100 prefix** when using Telegram Bot API:

 - `if` the channel ID is for example 1192292378
 - `then` you should use **-1001192292378**
```

#### Original Result

Open the private channel, then:

- on **web** client:
- look at the **URL** in your browser:
- `if` it's for example https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c1192292378_2674311763110923980
- `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID
- on **mobile** and **desktop**:
- copy the **link** of *any* message of the channel:
- `if` it's for example https://t.me/c/1192292378/31
- `then` **1192292378** is the channel ID (bonus: **31** is the message ID)
- on **Plus Messenger** [for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus&hl=en):
- open the **infos** of the channel:
- the channel ID appears **above**, right under its name

---

`WARNING` be sure to **add -100 prefix** when using Telegram Bot API:

- `if` the channel ID is for example 1192292378
- `then` you should use **-1001192292378**

Comment: Aren't there some Markdown [linters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)), local or online, that could be pointed to (for preventing the problem)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I link to the lists spec and that is it

Comment: [A recommendation](https://thisdavej.com/build-an-amazing-markdown-editor-using-visual-studio-code-and-pandoc/) for the "[markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint)" [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)  extension (near *"Install Markdown linter"*).